# Как настроить удаление файлов с помощью cmake?

Tags: cmake

Разобрался с установкой файлов с помощью `cmake`. Теперь встал вопрос: как их удалять? `make uninstall` - ничего не происходит, а при попытки задать комманду `uninstall` в `CMakeLists.txt` `cmake` ее не видит. Как задать удаление?

Comment: Готового решения нет: cmake [не создаёт цель uninstall](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Can_I_do_.22make_uninstall.22_with_CMake.3F), так что только если ручками создашь отдельную цель... на практике она практически никогда не нужна: удаление и установка системных файлов дело пакетного менеджера, а тестовые цели обычно решаются установкой в отдельный префикс или промежуточный каталог.

Comment: Цель uninstall не создает, а файл со списком установленных файлов создает. Можно делать просто `rm \`cat install_manifest.txt | xargs\``.